# Toggling language with Alt+Shift doesn't work

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, internationalization, language-support

On a recent install of 10.10 I can't toggle with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> between USA/Isr, even though I can toggle by pressing the language icon on the tool bar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you checked the keyboard preferences?

Go to System --> Preferences --> Keyboard --> "Layouts" Tab --> Options

and find the option "Key(s) to change layout"

[image]

Comment: Thanx, Its also the same under ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Ubuntu 14,the keyboard shortcut is **Super (Windows Logo) + Space bar**,it will toggle between the languages.

if you have more than two languages,shortcut for the next source is **Super (Windows Logo) + Space bar** and for the previous source is **Shift + Super (Windows Logo) + Space bar**.

you can change the shortcuts using **text entry** setting.

Answer (score 0):

Related to the feature you mentioned, there's currently an open issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/control-center/+bug/36812

Enabling the Alt+Shift key to toggle between languages will cause that Ctrl+Shift+Tab (used to reverse cycle through open child windows/documents) does not work. At least that's my experience. Is it working for you?

Comment: yes, it does.